# WCF client produces error I don't know

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am working on an assignment and I am getting this error which I don't understand. I am writing a WCF client for a working service. Can anyone help me out here?

This line is throwing the error:

```
MyComplex sumcplx = proxy.complex_sum(one,two);
```

Error I get

> Error: The best overloaded method match for 'NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTypes.CalculatorClient.complex_sum(NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes.MyComplex,NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes.MyComplex)' has some invalid arguments

Code to my program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace NETProxyWCFClient
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyComplex
    {
        int real;
        [DataMember]
        public int Real
        {
            get { return real; }
            set { real = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        int im;
        public int Im
        {
            get { return im; }
            set { im = value; }
        }

    }
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int mult(int a, int b);

        [OperationContract]
        List<int> fib(int n);

        [OperationContract]
        MyComplex complex_sum(MyComplex a, MyComplex b);
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in 2 numbers");
            string read = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = read.Split(' ');
            int m = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
            int n = int.Parse(numbers[1]);

            ProxyTypes.CalculatorClient proxy = new ProxyTypes.CalculatorClient();


            //Multiplcation
            int sum = proxy.mult(m, n);
            Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());


            //Mycomplex
            MyComplex one = new MyComplex();
            one.Im = m;
            one.Real = n;

            MyComplex two = new MyComplex();
            two.Im = n;
            two.Real = m;

            MyComplex sumcplx = proxy.complex_sum(one,two);
            Console.WriteLine(sumcplx.Im + " , " + sumcplx.Real);

            //fib one
            int[] listM = proxy.fib(m);
            foreach (int listItem in listM)
            {
                Console.Write(listItem.ToString() + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");

            //fib 2
            int[] listN = proxy.fib(n);
            foreach (int listItem in listN)
            {
                Console.Write(listItem.ToString() + " ");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not 100% clear from your code if all this code is in one project or not. do you have 2 project: a WCF project and an console EXE?
If not: fully qualify (w/ namespaces) in your decelerations of vars one and two. HTH

Comment: This is code for the client... The service which I have written as well has the exact same class and interfaces.. both console projects

Comment: If you have Added a service reference to your test program, there is a proxt class that is generated for you.  If you have ICalculator defined explicity (code you wrote) remove it.  it is already in your project, under the NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes.MyComplex,NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Added a service reference to your test program, there is a proxt class that is generated for you, so if you have ICalculator defined explicity (code you wrote) remove it. it is already in your project, under the NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes.MyComplex,NETProxyWCFClient.ProxyTpes namespace.